# MYSQL how to do a date between SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have following query which basically all i want to do is to select the end_date between today and +3 days in the future, however my query gives me non-sense results including dates in the future for even 3 months ? what i am i doing wrong here ? i tried the date between also but didnt work too

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( ccs.end_date, INTERVAL +3
DAY ) , DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ) , ccs. * , cc. *
FROM `customers_closure` cc, `customers_closure_service` ccs
WHERE cc.queue_id = '1'
AND ccs.closure_id = cc.id
AND (
ccs.end_date >= DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )
AND ccs.end_date <= DATE_ADD( ccs.end_date, INTERVAL +3
DAY )
)
ORDER BY cc.id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted

```
SELECT ccs . * , cc . *
                    FROM `customers_closure` cc, `customers_closure_service` ccs
                    WHERE cc.queue_id = '1'
                    AND ccs.closure_id = cc.id
                    AND 
                    (
                    ccs.end_date BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL +3 DAY AND CURDATE()
                    )

                    ORDER BY cc.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(ccs.end_date), ccs.*, cc. *
FROM `customers_closure` cc, `customers_closure_service` ccs
WHERE cc.queue_id = 1
AND ccs.closure_id = cc.id
AND DATE(ccs.end_date) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE( DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +3 DAY) )
ORDER BY cc.id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Give this a try.

Comment: Why bigger value first?

Comment: `DATE(ccs.end_date)` using columns in expressions prevents any index optimizations

Answer (score 0):

Are your `end_date` values DATETIMEs? If so you'd best avoid BETWEEN clauses.

Try this instead.

```
... ccs.end_date >= CURDATE()
AND ccs.end_date <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY
```

You do that (with the end of the range selected by a `<` instead of a `<=` and the range extended by a day for this reason: the end of your BETWEEN range leaves ou all the times of the end date except midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Just add +1 day to the wanted days you want to retrieve the data's. Like the code below:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( ccs.end_date, INTERVAL +4
DAY ) , DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ) , ccs. * , cc. *
FROM `customers_closure` cc, `customers_closure_service` ccs
WHERE cc.queue_id = '1'
AND ccs.closure_id = cc.id
AND (
ccs.end_date >= DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )
AND  ccs.end_date < DATE_ADD( NOW( ), INTERVAL + 4
DAY )
)
ORDER BY cc.id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```